# Find corrupt lines in textfiles and write them behind the line above

Tags: vba, text-files

I have around 400 textfiles with circa 41000 corrupt lines.

I am searching for an option (VBA maybe?) which searches for these corrupt lines and basically executes a backspace, so that the corrupt lines are written behind the line before, because the corruption is caused by an unwanted wordwrap. The indicator for corrupt lines is that they don't start with the letters TEQ.

Has anyone any idea how and where to build a script like that? Search and replace does not work since i cant but a backspace in the replace field obviously. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

An example of a corrupted line:

```
TEQ;231232;OFNENJD;29840389;TPOS;
TEQ;54111232;O2D;29829;
TPOS;
```

Line 3 is the corrupted one since it belongs to line 2 but there was a wordwrap. I need to execute a backspace to get it back behind line 2. That's what i'd like to have automated.

Comment: You could put a space in the "find"-field. (:

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But finding the lines is not my problem. I have sorted them out, but since there are 41K+ of them, i don't want to do the backspace manually 41 thousand times. So i need something to replace them all.

Comment: I have exports from excel. So every column is seperated with a semikolon.
For example it looks like this: 


TEQ;2341;GJGJG;092139;9078;dbhd;

TEQ;1241;GJGJG;093319;9018;dbhd;

;;

line 3 would be a corrupt one.

Comment: I edited the original post, it's better to show there.

Comment: No it's not. That was just a example, it can be anything, so i just check if it is TEQ or not. If not, it's corrupt. Always.
And yes, it's an exported excel file.

Comment: If the semi colons are field delimiters why not count them using an Instr loop? If there are less than 5 then you don't have a full set

Comment: Again, i do not have problems finding the corrupt lines. I already have a regex to find them.All i need is something that post a backspace infront of the corrupt ones so they jump back up to the right one again.

Answer (score 1):

To isolate the bad end-of-lines, first convert the good end-of-lines to an abstract. You can then remove the vbCrLF or vbLf which will have the effect of backspacing them away. The last step would be to restore the good end-of-lines by reversing the abstract.

```
dim str as string
'use your favorite method to read the TXT file into the str variable
str = Replace(str, chr(59) & vbCrLf & "TEQ;", chrw(8203))  'convert good eol to unicode zero-length space
str = Replace(str, vbLf, vbNullString)   'remove bad eols
str = Replace(str, chrw(8203), chr(59) & vbCrLf & "TEQ;")  'revert back to good eol
'write the str back to the TXT file
```

It wouldn't be a bad idea to throw a few of the .TXT files into a hex editor to determine whether the bad end-of-lines are created with vbCrLf (Chr(13) & Chr(10)) or just vbLf (Chr(10)). Same with the good end-of-lines although I suspect the good ones will be vbCrLF and the bad ones just vbLf.

> The following Sub procedure requires that you go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to the project.

```
Sub fix_TEQ_text()
    Dim str As String, fp As String, fn As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, ts As TextStream

    fp = Environ("TEMP")
    fn = Dir(fp & Chr(92) & "TEQ*.txt", vbNormal)

    Do While CBool(Len(fn))
        If Not CBool(InStr(1, fn, "_fixed", vbTextCompare)) Then
            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(fp & Chr(92) & fn, ForReading)
            str = ts.ReadAll
            ts.Close

            str = Replace(str, Chr(59) & vbCrLf & "TEQ;", ChrW(8203))  'convert good eol to unicode zero-length space
            str = Replace(str, vbLf, vbNullString)   'remove bad eols
            str = Replace(str, ChrW(8203), Chr(59) & vbCrLf & "TEQ;")  'revert back to good eol

            Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(fp & Chr(92) & Replace(fn, ".txt", "_fixed.txt"), True)
            ts.Write str
            ts.Close

        End If
        fn = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

You will want to change the file path (e.g. **fp**) and the file mask (currently `"TEQ*.txt"` which matched my sample TXT files).

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you correctly, but is this to find the end of corrupted lines?

Comment: An end-of-line/line feed/carriage return/paragraph is just some ASCII control codes; typically either ASCII character 0×0D (Chr(13)) followed by   0×0A (Chr(10)) or just 0×0A by itself. There is not pattern to the bad ones but there is to the good ones. If you replace the good ones with something else then you have isolated the bad ones. Deal with teh bad ones and then revert the change you made to the good ones.

Comment: Okay i get it. But what i need is exactly where you say "Deal with the bad ones". I have 41000 rows that are corrupted and need just one backspace infront of them. But doing that manually would take me a week or so. I just need a line of code that dows a backspace whenever i have a corrupt line.

Comment: I gave you that above. The second replace remove all line feeds. It is safe to do this because the first replace disguised the good lines feeds. The third replace puts the good ones back. edit: I'm working on a short program for you to demonstrate. I wish you could pass over one of the files. I really would like to see it in a hex editor.

Comment: i would pass them over but since it's for work i can't for data security reasons.

Comment: As I implied above, I strongly suspect that the good EOLs are vbCRLF and the rogue ones vbLF. I'll try to compensate blindly.

Comment: Okay i found a pretty easy solution. Just hitting STRG+F in Notepad++ and click on 'Find in Files'. Then in Search i put '\R([^T][^e][^q])' and in Replace a simple '\1'. That does the trick!

Comment: That might be a bit monotonous with 400 files to process.

Comment: No because notepad has the option to search all files in one folder. So i can check them all with one go.

Comment: You're right of course. I use the Find-in-Files all the time but only replace the data rarely.