# Removing unwanted data from text file

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a large text file exported from an application that has three unwanted zeros in each row. The text file needs to be imported into another application and the zeros cause a problem.

Basically the unwanted three zeros per row need to be deleted. These zeros are always in the same location (same number of characters when counting from the left), but the location is somewhere in the middle. I have tried various things like importing the file into excel, removing the zeroes and then exporting as text file, but always have formatting problems with the exported text file.

Can someone suggest a solution or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use VBA's `mid()` function to remove the zeros and write the output to another file. Use that cleaned up file for the next steps of your process

Comment: See [Find corrupt lines in textfiles and write them behind the line above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519650/find-corrupt-lines-in-textfiles-and-write-them-behind-the-line-above/32520508#32520508) for boilerplate code designed to open a TXT file, make modifications and save it as a new file.

Answer (score 2):

something like this ? (quickly done)

```
Sub replaceInTx()
    Dim inFile As String, outFile As String
    Dim curLine As String

    inFile = "x:\Documents\test.txt"
    outFile = inFile & ".new.txt"

    Open inFile For Input As #1
    Open outFile For Output As #2

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, curLine
        Print #2, Replace(curLine, "000", "", 6, 1, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
    Close #1
    Close #2
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can do that with any **text editor** that allows *block selection* (I like Notepad2, tiny, fast and portable)

Comment: the first zero is always at 104th position, when counting from the left. I tried replacing 6 above with 104, but it is not working as it should. How can I make sure that 104, 105 and 106th items are replaced with ""

Comment: by using a combination of LEFT() and MID() ?

Comment: Can you give an example please? i tried with mid() and left() but not getting it right

Answer (score 1):

I see you use excel a lot.
When you import the text file into excel do you use the import function and do you push the data into separate cells?
if the cell is numeric you could do the following:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(G5,"#"),LEN(TEXT(G5,"#"))-3)
```

if the cell is text:

```
=LEFT(G5,LEN(G5)-3)
```

G5 would the cell the data row/field is in.

Comment: I am not allowed to comment but your answer is kind of above anyway:

Answer (score 1):

```
curLine = Left(curLine, 104)
```

This will take the first 104 characters